# How to Pointer Output in Programs?

Tags: c, pointers

In a quiz today, we got this as our question2.

After seeing this, most of us believe that we will fail quite badly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( ) {
  char str[] = "StanfordIsGreat";

  char *ptr = str;

  printf("%s", ptr);
  printf("%s", ptr + 8);
  printf("%s", ptr + 'l' - 'b');
  printf("%s", ptr + 'k' - ptr[3]);
}
```

So can anyone guide me answer this question?

what i applied for 1st printf was that the actual string will be printed `StanfordIsGreat`

for 2nd printf, i think the pointer will shift 8 indexes to the right generating `IsGreat`

for 3rd printf, ptr + 'l' gave me `StanfordIsGreatl`, i didn't understand what  `- 'b'`  meant

for 4rth printf ptr + 'k' was same as above and ptr[3] stands for 'a' so i wrote `StnfordisGretk`

i am really confused about 3rd and 4rth, can someone guide me, so i can learn and not make mistakes like this for future quizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char str[] = "StanfordIsGreat";
```

Character array(string) which contains content StanfordIsGreat.

```
char *ptr = str;
```

Character pointer that points to the 1st letter of the string (S).

```
printf("%s", ptr);
```

Direct printing the string pointed from the pointer index till the end of the string hence 
`Output: StanfordIsGreat`

```
printf("%s", ptr + 8);
```

Pointer is shifted 8 index, pointing to 'I' in StanfordIsGreat therefore printing from 'I' to end of string 
`Output: IsGreat`

```
printf("%s", ptr + 'l' - 'b');
```

Easy if you know the ASCII values for 'l' and 'b', here you must subtract the ASCII values of 'l' and 'b' giving you 10, giving you equation `ptr+10` which equals pointer pointing to 'G'. 
`Output: Great`

```
printf("%s", ptr + 'k' - ptr[3]);
```

Same as above but tricking you with ptr with index, ptr[3] points to 'n' therefore now you must subtract 'k' and 'n', giving you a -ve value, an unexpected behaviour will rise due to ptr-value. 
`Output: Not Clear Since we don't have a memory pool to overview`

Edited: thanks **mch** for clearing an error :)

Hope you understand :)

Comment: Given that C does not mandate ASCII, the third and fourth `printf()`s could easily index out of bounds.

Comment: `ptr[3]` is `'n'`, not `'a'`, so the resulting pointer in the last `printf` will point before the array and so it will invoke undefined behaviour.